# Http request in pine script

Tags: httprequest, listener, pine-script

I've done a lot of research on how to fetch data from an API in pine script to plot it on chart or trigger an alert.

I have an API that gives me buy/sell signals. I want pine script calls the API to fetch new signals and plot them so the user can decide whether to use them.

Another approach that works for me is to implement an endpoint in pine script so I can send data to that endpoint.

I would appreciate guidance if any approach can help. Otherwise, a strict NO can make me totally sure it is not possible.

Comment: http(s) calls in pine script is impossible now 100%